# Words for “everyday details” that illustrate life

Tags: expressions

When talking about things used in a performance to illustrate conditions of life (like jam-jars and baskets to show village life), can I call them *everyday details*?

Comment: Perhaps _everyday accoutrements_

Comment: *Details* isn't ideal, I'd be expecting facts more than objects. "Everyday" is fine but *objects*, *items*, or just *things* all work better than *details*.

Answer (score 1):

*Household  [objects or items](http://www.ehow.com/list_7571416_different-household-items.html)* is a common definition:

> The term "household items" can entail a variety of objects. It is a term used to specify items frequently found in the home but can include everything from a cleaning mop to a shovel and even glue or tape.

Comment: And if they don't want to be restricted to the household, there's "everyday objects" and "everyday items".